# Last N days:2, Want to query the records of past 2 day alone on the created date of the record

Tags: soql

have to query the record of the article which is created on past 2 day alone.tried using this SOQL but its not returning the correct values.

```
SELECT id, CreatedDate, CreatedById, Flag_It__c, Knowledge_Article_Lookup__r.Title 
FROM Knowledge_FeedBack__c 
WHERE CreatedDate = Last_N_Days:2 AND CreatedDate < Last_N_Days:3
```

Comment: If you remove the `AND CreatedDate < Last_N_Days:3`, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get rid of `AND CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:3`. `CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:2` should be enough for your requirement.

Here is the documentation for your reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Comment: thanks for your help.. i have followed your steps. the result I got.. the query resulted by pulling all the records of last 2 days, but my actual requirement is to get the record of past 2nd(day before yesterday's record only) date only.

Comment: you can add `AND CreatedDate != LAST_N_DAYS:1` on a where clause. It should works.